# Install Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse-plugin

What is the easiest way to install plugin for Eclipse ? 
Is there a Generic structure for all plug-ins so I can examine the feature that they offer ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is Help/Eclipse Marketplace.